# Trying to resolve justify position in flex div

Tags: html, css, reactjs, tailwind-css

I have an issue which happend frequently.
here's my code:

```
<div className="flex flex-col w-full mb-3">
  <div className="flex flex-row w-full">
    {
      Vege &&
        <p className="mr-1 text-sm leading-6 text-green-500">{Vege ? "VÉGÉ • " : ""}</p>
    }
  <p className="font-bold">{Titre}</p>
  <p className="justify-end">{Prix} €</p>
 </div>
 <p>{Description}</p>
</div>
```

I can't manage to make the p tag including {Prix} € to be at the end of the line.
It happends to me on multiple parts of my code... Do you have any idea how to make this work?

lot of search and test, but can't find the right thing to do.

edit:
here's a [picture](https://i.stack.imgur.com/xKol0.png) of what the code gives me
And here's what i want to achieve [in this picture](https://i.stack.imgur.com/bkOpQ.png)

Comment: can you please exactly describe what the current state is and how you want it to be? Maybe with some pictures?

Comment: ok! i'll add some pictures

Answer (score 0):

You just need to give the element with the `font-bold` class the CSS property `flex: 1`. Provided that all others do not have `flex` set.

Unfortunately, I can’t tell you which class is responsible for this in tailwind.

Answer (score 0):

@Andrei
There are some solutions and you can change like this.

```html
<p className="font-bold flex-auto">{Titre}</p>
<p className="ml-1">{Prix} €</p>
```

Good luck

Answer (score 0):

you can use the class `flex-grow` on the previous element (which translates to the CSS: `flex-grow:1`)

```html
<p className="font-bold flex-grow">{Titre}</p>
<p>{Prix} €</p>
```

demo: https://livecodes.io/?x=id/d7j5axrx5sy&compiled=open (check the compiled CSS)

Comment: ok so flex grow will take all the remaining place given by the parent div, thanks mate